# What is defines the User aspect for the generation of Settings.Secure.Android_ID

Tags: android

I am just finishing up testing on a new version of an android app and have generated a signed apk for release, I noticed that the value generated for Settings.Secure.Android_ID is different to the version that is currently live on the play store despite being signed by the same key.

I am wondering if this is because I have side loaded the apk rather than installing from the play store, my thinking is that the "user" aspect of the ANDROID_ID generation is influenced by the play store user signed into the play store and by side loading the apk the user is different.

I have installed the signed APK and the current play store version of the app on the same phone and both always generate the same ANDROID_ID but they don't match each other.

Comment: From my understanding, Play Store verifies your app's signature, then resign it with their signature

Comment: On recent versions of Android you don't have access to the real Android ID instead Android derives an app specific Android ID that does not change as long as the real Android ID does not change. If you use a different app (not sure if the app is different because of the pacakageName, the signature cert or both) then you will get a different Android ID.

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel that was it, all sorted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned by @ShlomiKatriel Google signs your apk when they approve it and put it live so the playstore version will generate a different ANDROID_ID than the signed APK that is side loaded but the key is always the same and as such so is the ANDROID_ID.